# Is this how COALESCE works in this MS SQL Query: ORDER BY COALESCE([UpdatedOn], [CreatedOn]) DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I'm reviewing some SQL statement which uses a `COALESCE` statement in an `ORDER BY`. I've read the docs about `COALESCE` so i'm trying to understand if I understand how it's getting used, in this scenario.

This is the part of the sql statement:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE([UpdatedOn], [CreatedOn]) DESC
```

Is it trying to say this (via some fake data I've made up):

** Note: DateFormat is `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
 ELID |  LK   |  CreatedOn |  UpdatedOn | Computed-OrderBy
+---------------------------------------------------------
    1 | 'aaa' | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02
    2 | 'bbb' | 2020-01-01 |       NULL | 2020-01-01
```

so then, that is the result (in memory, etc) and SQL Server will order the results in the `Computer-OrderBy` column (which we never really see)

So the results would be ordered:

```
ELID 2 - 2020-01-01
ELID 1 - 2020-01-02
```

UPDATE 1: If the `COALESCE` was in a `SELECT` statement, then I wouldn't be asking a question because I grok it. I'm asking about when `ORDER BY` 'ing .. how SQL sorta does it, behind the scenes. Notice how I've made up a new column `Computed-OrderBy` ? Well, I was hoping to see if that's more-or-less what Sql Server does ... so it knows how to order by *those* 'computed' values.

Comment: So, what are you actually asking here, what does `COALESCE` do? Have you reviewed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to see if my understanding of COALESCE is correct. As in, behind the scenes this is what is going on. I'll update my post to reflect your question.

Comment: Put `COALESCE([UpdatedOn], [CreatedOn])` in the SELECT list to see what it returns.

Comment: @jarlh I'm trying to see ... not the records that were returned .. but how SQL SERVER handles the `COALESCE` in the `ORDER BY`. So if you look at my sample data .. that was me pretending to be SQL SERVER .. with some in memory temp result, before it does the ORDERING.

Comment: COALESCE will move from left to right, and use the first value it finds that isn't NULL. So your row with ELID = 1 would be "computed" to be 2020-01-01. COALESCE basically says "use one of the following, the first one from left to right that isn't NULL".

Comment: Thanks @CaptainKenpachi for the comment. So how I wrote up the 'fake data' .. is just like you're saying, then?

Comment: Oh yes, you have the order reversed in your statement, so it's correct then.

Comment: thank you! can you please make an answer then so I can give you the points, plz.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation on [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it does the following:

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL. For example, `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');` returns the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't null.

The fact that `COALESCE` is in the `ORDER BY` doesn't change that. `COALESCE` will return the value of `UpdatedOn` if it is a non-`NULL` value, and then then value of `CreatedOn`. If both are `NULL` then `NULL` will be returned.

As the expression is in the `ORDER BY`, then your results will then be put in (ascending) order based on the result of the expression, with rows that have `NULL` returned for the expression being treated as having the lowest value, and the date `9999-12-31` having the greatest.